# Django context variable names for the templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-class-based-views

EDIT:
I know I can change the names of the variables. My question is in the case that I don't want to do that. I want to know what are all the variables that django generates automatically.

---

I'm doing Django's getting started tutorial and I'm on the [generic views section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial04/) where at one point it explains:

> In previous parts of the tutorial, the templates have been provided
>   with a context that contains the question and latest_question_list
>   context variables. For DetailView the question variable is provided
>   automatically – since we’re using a Django model (Question), Django is
>   able to determine an appropriate name for the context variable.
>   However, for ListView, the automatically generated context variable is
>   question_list.

My problem is that I don't know how Django determines this "appropriate names". I want to know this for when I write my own template. I would want to know what context variable names to use in such template.

From what I can understand, if my model is `Question`, the `question` context variable would store that question, and the `question_list` context variable would store every question.

So my doubt is: What other context variables names can I use? and what would they store? I can't seem to find this on the documentation, please redirect me to it if you know where it is.

Comment: FYI you can set the context template variables yourself setting `context_object_name = 'yourname'` as the view attribute.

Comment: Yes, I know I can set this names myself. My question is in the case that I don't want to set those names. I want to know what are the variables that django generates automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the question_list to something else by using the [context_object_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.context_object_name) this isn't explained all that well in that part of the documentation, but ...

> Return the context variable name that will be used to contain the list
>   of data that this view is manipulating. If object_list is a queryset
>   of Django objects and context_object_name is not set, the context name
>   will be the model_name of the model that the queryset is composed
>   from, with postfix '_list' appended. For example, the model Article
>   would have a context object named article_list.

is given under [get_context_object_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_context_object_name) method

This is what that method's [code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/list.py#L115) looks like, It ought to clear up all doubts:

```
    """
    Get the name of the item to be used in the context.
    """
    if self.context_object_name:
        return self.context_object_name
    elif hasattr(object_list, 'model'):
        return '%s_list' % object_list.model._meta.model_name
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: I thought each generic view generated more than one context variable. that [code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/list.py) helped. Thanks

Comment: glad to have helped

Answer (score 2):

I think this default context variable name only applies when dealing with Django's Class Based Views.

E.g. If you are using a DetailView for a Animal model, Django will auto create a context variable called 'animal' for you to use in template. I think it also allows the use of 'object'.

Another example is, as you mentioned, the ListView for a Animal model which would generate context name called animal_list.

However, in both of these cases, there are ways to change the default context variable name. If you specify 'context_object_name' in your DetailView, this will be the name you refer to in your template. This will also work for ListViews.

This website has all info on CBVs of all Django versions:

https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.9/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/